# Can geometry be partially hidden by manipulating the far plane of the camera?

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to manipulate the camera far plane to hide a portion of a THREE.Line object. However, I must be doing something wrong.

I set the near- and far plane using:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2, 0);
```

Next, I create the geometry:

```
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -2)); // outside far plane
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -3)); // outside far plane
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -2)); // outside far plane
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
```

Finally, I create the line and add it to the scene:

```
lines = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
lines.frustumCulled = true; // default?
scene.add(lines);
```

The entire object is shown in the frustum.

Please see fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/g52w4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `near` and `far` plane parameters are distances (from the camera). They should be positive, with the `far` greater than the `near`.

Set your `far` plane to 5, for example.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpT5K/

three.js r.65